# Utilizando valores variáveis

Tags: amazon-aws, golang

Tenho esse código em GO e como podem ver utilizo duas constantes para passar a região e o nome do bucket.
Gostaria de saber como poderia deixar esses valores variáveis, visto que posso utilizar buckets em outras regiões e com outros nomes.

```
package main


import (
"bytes"
"encoding/csv"
"log"
"net/http"
"os"

"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

const (
    S3_REGION = "sa-east-1"
    S3_BUCKET = "teste-csv"
)

var data = [][]string{{"Line1", "Hello Readers of"}, {"Line2", "golangcode.com"}}

func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("result.csv")
    checkError("Cannot create file", err)
    defer file.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    for _, value := range data {
        err := writer.Write(value)
        checkError("Cannot write to file", err)
    }


    s, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(S3_REGION)})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = AddFileToS3(s, "result.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func checkError(message string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(message, err)
    }
}


    file, err := os.Open(fileDir)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
    var size int64 = fileInfo.Size()
    buffer := make([]byte, size)
    file.Read(buffer)

    // of the file you're uploading.
    _, err = s3.New(s).PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:               aws.String(S3_BUCKET),
        Key:                  aws.String(fileDir),
        ACL:                  aws.String("private"),
        Body:                 bytes.NewReader(buffer),
        ContentLength:        aws.Int64(size),
        ContentType:          aws.String(http.DetectContentType(buffer)),
        ContentDisposition:   aws.String("attachment"),
        ServerSideEncryption: aws.String("AES256"),
    })
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apenas troque a palavra chave `const` por `var`, deste jeito você conseguira trocar os valores contidos nas variaveis, veja com mais detalhe na [documentação oficial](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#pkg-constants)

Answer (score 0):

Como disse o [RFL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360318/97971), você pode trocar de constante para variável e alterar o valor no código. Tem outro método, se o código for o mesmo para outras regiões e buckets, você pode receber esses valores pelo argumento

`const (
  S3_REGION = os.Args[1]
  S3_BUCKET = os.Args[2]
)`

E quando for rodar o executável basta colocar depois do nome `seu.exe sa-east-1 teste-csv`. [Aqui tem um exemplo do *Go by Example*](https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments), não tem muito segredo.